# Cytoscape node pie chart as mean ± sd

Tags: r, cytoscape

I have GNPS network on cytoscape and wanted to label each feature node as representation of the sample, sample has multiple experiment, I can only show mean values as either float point or integer but I wanted to label as showing both mean and standard deviation (sd), somthing like mean ± sd as string. So I concatenate both mean and sd as text, however, it does not accept string column for labeling. Pie chart only accepts columns with number values does the percent itself that is representative of the associatedarea of the chart, for example, 1921 (22%) is average of five replicate but i wanted to show average ± sd = like this 1921 ± 56, however i did not find any way to show the mean with standard errors.

Please suggest any solution or any R packages that does that, or refer to any suggested reading, how can i show the associated standard error as mean ± sd. I truly appreciate your help. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cytoscape app (I'm assuming you're talking about Cytoscape desktop here) called enhancedGraphics that provides lots of flexibility for labeling pie charts.  You may want to take a look at that and see if it does what you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and yes, you are right, i am using desktop cytoscape. I think I did a quick look at the enhancedGraphics but was not able to find any solution, I will double check again.